# What kind of training strategies are there and what is there purpose?

Tags: training

There are different ways of training:

- low intensity for a long duration
- intervall
- short and intense
- with resting days in between or without

are things which I have seen being mentioned

Can somebody give an overview for what kind of purpose what kind of training would be useful?

- muscle volume
- strength
- endurance
- weight loss
- ...

As discussed in the comments, I'm not looking for tons of details, but a rough overview how different types of trainings get classified and what they are used for.

Comment: This is a very broad question. There are close to infinitely varied methods for training. Even when looking at a single sport, there is an amazing amount of different training methods and styles.

Comment: This question is far too broad to be answered in a reasonable manner. (Several) Books could be written about this. Please ask questions based on problems that you face.

Comment: Just what are we talking about here?  Running and lifting have two very different applications with some overlapping concepts.  Same with sport specific exercise.  It starts reading like you're talking about running/swimming/cycling but ends like you might be considering weight training as well?

Comment: @Informaficker This is a problem I'm facing. I'm just looking for an overview, for someone with some experience in training planning this should be doable in a couple paragraphs.

Comment: I'm not talking a specifc (type of) sport. Although I guess certain kinds of sport are more suitable for certain kinds of training. I guess that's why people the do one sport do something completely different as part of their training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do my best to link these up:

> **low intensity for a long duration** - endurance, weight loss
>
> **intervall** - endurance
>
> **short and intense** - strength (powerlifters usually lift very heavy weights very few times)
>
> **medium length and intensity** - muscle volume
>
> **with rest days** - powerlifters and endurance athletes usually take days off to recuperate.
>
> **without rest days** - bodybuilders usually don't take rest days because they stress muscles much more than joints/tendons.

Hope that gives the general outline.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a very broad brush. I know quite a few endurance athletes (running/triathlon/cycling) that do not take days off at all, they just do easier workouts. Any answer short of 10 pages is going to be woefully incomplete. Also, bodybuilders don't take rest days per se because they work opposite groups on given days, and many bbers do take one or two rest days in a given period.

Comment: Agreed, there is much flexibility in how each type of athlete can train, and yes good point about bodybuilders working different groups every day (in most cases).